# VBA SAP occasional error Control ID Not Found

Tags: vba, error-handling, sap-gui

In the below code I am extracting data from SAP. In a few SAP reports I am running, occasionally data is not available, in which a pop up box appears, displaying

> No Data Exists For Chosen Selection

I've implemented the below error handling strategy, which works fine when debugging and stepping into the code, but running in totality I receive this error on the asterik denoted line:

> The Control Could Not Be Found By ID

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press

On Error GoTo ResumeInterCompany
**If session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]").Text = "No data exists for chosen selection" Then**
GoTo TroubleShootInterCompany

End If
```

Any suggestions. I can provide more relevant code if need be.

Comment: There's no toolbar at index 0? Where's no window at index 1? FWIW there's 100% a better way to do whatever you're trying to do, than using `GoTo` jumps.

Comment: You should check to make sure your findById method returns a object, before trying to click it.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is as follows:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press

On Error Resume next
myText = "x"
err.clear 
myText = session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]").Text
if err.number <> 0 then myText = ""
on error goto 0
If myText = "No data exists for chosen selection" Then
   GoTo TroubleShootInterCompany
End If
```

Regards,
ScriptMan